# Deleting a View in a class method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, cardview

In my activity I try to call a method from a class but it's not getting the right values.
This is ActivityTwo:

```
int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View mainActivity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

LinearLayout eventsLayout = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.eventsLayout);
Log.d("ACTIVITY_eventlayout", String.valueOf(eventsLayout)); // gives the layout perfectly
Event.RemoveSpecific(eventsLayout, id);

finish();
```

This is the class(Event) with the method:

```
public static void RemoveSpecific(LinearLayout layout, int id){
        View event = layout.findViewById(id);
        Log.d("INSIDE_removespecific", String.valueOf(event));// event is null
        layout.removeView(event);
}
```

And in my MainActivity it's working fine:

```
LinearLayout eventsLayout = findViewById(R.id.eventsLayout);
View event = eventsLayout.findViewById(id);
//Log.d("MAIN_event", String.valueOf(event1)); // gives it perfectly
eventsLayout.removeView(event);
```

I also add this view in my MainActivity and use `.setId(id)` to give it the right id. So my question is, why is the View in my class method null, while I pass the right LinearLayout from my activityTwo?

Where does the id come from?

I have the Event class which contains an id, name, date, & description. This class also has a static ArrayList called eventsList. Whenever the user creates a new reminder I create a new Event using my class and giving it an id as `Event.eventsList().size()` (after adding it to my eventsList [so the first event id is always 1]), then I create a new View and pass the recently created Event details and use `setId()` to give it an id [1]. Then in this View I have a button which has an onClickListener which passes the given View id and the LinearLayout (where the View was added) to my `Event.removeSpecific()` method.

App flow:

The user clicks a button in MainActivity to create an event, then the button click then use `startActivityForResult()` with an intent to open a new Activity where the user puts in a name,description and date for the event, then I create an intent with `putExtra()` methods and then use `setResult(RESULT_OK, resultintent)` to send the data back to MainActivity. Now when the MainActivity gets the data back I use `.getStringExtra()` to create a new Event object with the data and add it to may `Event.eventsList` ArrayList, then I use the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View event_Exmaple = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_example, null);
```

and set the textView's with the data I got, and use event_`example.setId(Event.eventsList.size())` to give it an id.
After that I add this to my LinearLayout (which I declared already in the MainActivity):

```
eventsLayout.addView(event_example)
```

Now I mentioned that the Event class has a date field. I use that to set up an alarm with AlarmManager. With the AlarmManager I send the current Event object's data through the intent and when the user gets the notification it opens up a new Activity which gets the given Event object data (with `intent.putExtra()`'s) and that's the part where the user clicks on a Button. I want to remove the given Event object's View from my LinearLayout in the MainActivity XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well since you didn't share where the **id** value come from (from where the intent gets its data/how you put the values in it/where the values come from), I assumed this solution :

- whenever I use a 'switch' statement with View Ids it tells me a very important warning which is

> Resource IDs will be non-final in Android Gradle Plugin version 5.0, avoid using them in switch case statements

- that means that view Ids doesn't have a stable id in some cases that you shouldn't consider them to be final.
- I guess in your case when you get an id to your **event view** and then inflate the **layout view**, the inflate procedure involve changing the 'int' id value of the **event view** so whenever you query the old id it returns null since the **event view** inside the inflated **layout view** now has a new 'int' id value.
- I don't know why it works in main activity since you didn't share full code where you get the id from.
- so I guess the only solution is that you should find a way to get a fresh copy of the id after you inflate the view you want to work on in the method.

***Update***

the problem is with this block of code
`View mainActivity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);`
everytime you inflate a new layout view thinking that you have the one used by main activity back there but instead you're creating an entirely new one with new views and new Id's.
that would be why you could get the view in main activity but you can't get it from a newly inflated view.

***Update***

if you need to remove this item using the id and have a static array stored in the view custom class, call a getter on the static array and remove the item from it instead of trying to remove the view itself.

a better implementation of the whole situation is to store these events in a database using room instead of the static array, that way you could delete/add/edit any event anytime with just one line of code, if you're willing to do this you can start by reading the developers [documentation](http://this%20link%20developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) of room.

Comment: if you can share more code, maybe other people including or excluding me find a better cause and solution to your problem IDK

Comment: I edited my question, hope it clears up my idea a bit, maybe I should rewrite the whole thing since I see too that it's not really straightforward?

Comment: oh yeah I see now, I didn't notice that you mentioned "event" as a class that extends View, the edit info is very valuable indeed and modifying your post surely puts your question again at top as a new question so I guess there's no need to repost the question now

Comment: anyway if still no one found a solution to your problem and you decided anytime to repost the question be sure to include this custom class code, maybe that helps and you find quicker help next time, I will think about another solution and get back to you if I have found it.

Comment: about this block of code `View mainActivity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
`, do you inflate a whole new main activity view everytime a button is clicked other than the one you passed as a return value in onCreateView ? because a new inflated view won't contain same views that exist in the main one, it will create new views with new ids.

Comment: that would be why you could get the view in main activity but you can't get it from a newly inflated view other than the one that the main activity uses.

Comment: I updated the question again, explaining what my app do.

Comment: yes I think I guessed right, you do inflate a new layout view thinking that you have the one used by main activity back there but instead you're creating an entirely new one with new views.

Comment: And what do you suggest, can I pass the already done layout?

Comment: no you can't indeed, if you do have some items stored in a static array inside your custom view, why don't you just call a getter on the Custom class to get this array and remove the item you want to remove from the array itself. (since the item_id == item_pos +1, if you will remove the item from the array be sure to remove one's with position `id-1` not id)

Comment: if that solves your problem that will probably create a new problem that if you do remove  item at position 5, items at positions 6 ,7 ,8 will be shifted to the left and will be at position 5,6,7, later when an event with id = 6 comes to delete himself, he will delete the one with id 7 instead, so if you'll go down that way, you can't use `ArrayList.remove(int position)` method, instead you need to for loop on them and delete the event with the prober id

Comment: a better implementation of the whole situation is to store this events in a database using room instead of the static array, that way you could delete/add/edit any event anytime with just one line of code, if you're willing to do this you can start by reading the developers documentation of room through this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: I wanted to make the whole project using a database, but I wanted to test it locally to see how it would work, I guess using a database is generally easier for these type of projects, thanks for your answears it really helped me a lot!

Comment: no problem, thank you too for your updates it helped me understand the problem better.